# Можно ли отправить комментарий человеку, который не комментировал и не отвечал на вопрос?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, комментарии

Например есть какой-то вопрос, и мы отправляем коммент левому человеку, который даже не видел этот вопрос. Отправится ли ему комментарий? Самому попробовать как-то страшно, вдруг винда слетит XD

Comment: Нет, не отправится. Получатель должен как-то поучаствовать в жизни вопроса.

Comment: Если при наборе `@` ник участника не предлагается, то ему ничего отправить вы не можете, исключение здесь — когда в ветке комментариев всего 1 человек (помимо автора), уведомления ему отправляются автоматически

Comment: @АндрейNOP это не совсем так. Редакторы уведомляются, но @ не подставляет их ник.

Comment: @alexolut, это точно?

Comment: @АндрейNOP [точно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/339911)

Comment: @alexolut, спасибо, т.е. еще и закрывашки/открывашки, назначивший баунти. Неплохо бы перевести сообщение, чтобы была и у нас инфа эта

Comment: @АндрейNOP Вроде перевел. Есть конечно немного ошибочек, но думаю поймут)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать синтаксис *@name* в любом месте вашего комментария, чтобы ответить конкретному пользователю. Пользователь получит уведомление в своих [*входящих сообщениях*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/). Также, будет послано [уведомление по электронной почте](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/), если будут установлены соответствующие настройки, которые можно найти на странице профиля.

#### Кто может быть уведомлен таким способом?

- Автор сообщения.

  Обратите внимание, что автор сообщения *всегда* будет уведомлен о любом новом комментарии. Вы можете использовать его для ясности, если это необходимо; однако, если только вы и автор комментировали сообщение, *@name* будет автоматически удалено с начала комментария, за ненадобностью.
- Любой пользователь, у которого есть видимый (не удаленный) комментарий к сообщению.

  Обратите внимание, что если пользователь комментирует свое собственное сообщение, и есть только один человек, который ранее прокомментировал эту запись, то он [также будет уведомлен](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts), даже если *@name* не будет использовано.
- Любой пользователь, который отредактировал сообщение (не включая отклоненные правки и еще не принятые правки).
- В случае вопросов: модератор или владелец золотого знака, который закрыл или повторно открыл вопрос единолично. Пользователи, которые закрыли или повторно открыли вопрос *без* решающего голоса за закрытие (т. е. без золотого знака по метке или голоса модератора), и те, чей голос был решающим, но другие пользователи уже голосовали (например, закрыт участниками `User1`, `User2` и `Moderator`), не будут уведомляться.
- В случае вопросов: любой пользователь, который открывал конкурс на вопросе (текущий или истекший)

Имейте в виду, что вопрос и ответы рассматриваются независимо. Например, если Алиса была автором вопроса, то вы не можете уведомить ее, комментируя ответ Боба (если только Алиса не участвовала в этом ответе). Точно так же вы не можете уведомить Боба, комментируя вопрос Алисы.

#### Почему некоторые имена не отображаются в подсказке?

Подсказка сама определяет, когда *@name* не нужен для посылки уведомления, и в этом случае пользователь не будет включен в список.

Кроме того, только пользователи, которые уже комментировали сообщение, будут добавлены в список. Редакторы и другие пользователи из истории сообщения никогда не добавляются в подсказку, даже если они могут быть уведомлены при ручном наборе.

#### Можно ли уведомить более одного человека за раз?

Нет. Комментарии, содержащие более одного *@name*, [блокируются](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/should-we-discourage-the-user-of-multiple-redundant-username-pings/2615#2615), если они не содержат обратную кавычку `` ` `` .
В этом случае будет [уведомлен](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2035/notify-user-when-their-name-is-mentioned-in-comment/35914#35914) только первый участник, указанный с помощью *@name*. Например, *@alice `@bob Hi!`* Уведомит Алису (если она принимала участие в этом сообщении), но не Боба.

Исключением является случай, когда первое *@name* либо никому не соответствует, либо соответствует автору сообщения (и, следовательно, не обязательно); в этом случае будет проверяться следующее *@name*.

#### Можно ли изменить получателя уведомления после отправки комментария?

При редактировании комментария в пределах его ограниченного периода редактирования, если изменяется или добавляется *@name*, [уведомление может дойти или нет до нового получателя](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40989/will-edited-comments-reach-addressees/74781#74781), в зависимости от времени.

#### Существуют ли специальные ключевые слова для уведомления пользователей?

Нет. Такие вещи, как [*@op*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52368/does-op-also-notify-the-op), [*@downvoter*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post) или `@all`, не имеют особого значения и не будут вызывать никаких уведомлений.

#### Как проверяется указанные имена?

- Вы должны указать *@name*, где *name* соответствует [текущему отображаемому имени](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/481203#481203) пользователя во время отправки комментария. Нельзя использовать предыдущие отображаемые имена, которые мог иметь пользователь.
- Уведомление должно начинаться с пробела или быть в начале комментария. Например, вы [не можете использовать разметку](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39/whats-your-favourite-quote-about-programming/1079#comment-19850), такую ​​как курсив.
- Если первое слово в отображаемом имени длиной не менее трех символов, тогда оно должно начинаться с *name* не учитывая регистр. Это означает, что *@a* и *@ab* никогда не будут соответствовать никому, пока первое слово в отображаемом имени не содержит только два символа. Например: *@Jo* уведомит *Jo Miller*, но не *John* и *@B.* уведомит *B. Gates*, но не *B.Gates*. Если в *@name* больше трех символов, то все они должны быть в отображаемом имени (ни *@alix*, ни *@aliceinwonderland* не будут соответствовать пользователю *Alice*).
- Проверка осуществляется в обратном хронологическом порядке, то есть, если участвуют пять человек по имени john, `@john` будет соответствовать последнему Джону. (Используйте следующее правило для уточнения.)
- Пробелы удаляются из *отображаемых имен* при сопоставлении. Поэтому, чтобы указать Peter Smith, вы можете использовать *@pet*, *@peter*, *@peters*, или *@petersmith*. Последние два полезны, если также участвует Peter Jones, который затем может быть указан как *@peterj*. Однако в самом *@name* не допускается использование пробелов. Поэтому уведомления *P Smith*, нужно использовать *@psm* или *@psmith*. (*@P Smith* будет обрабатываться как просто *@P*, что слишком мало.) Одиночные кавычки, точки, тире и символы подчеркивания [не должны](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51911/the-dot-in-username-within-first-3-character-preventing-from-comment-replies/51913#51913) удаляться.
- Специальные символы заменяются их простым вариантом. Чтобы ответить на Piëre, вы можете использовать как *@piëre*, так и *@piere*. И чтобы ответить Jörg, вы можете использовать *@jorg*, [но не](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89051/joerg-works-for-jorg) *@joerg*.

#### Влияют ли знаки пунктуации на отправку уведомлений?

Система пытается игнорировать большинство знаков пунктуации, такие как точка, запятая или двоеточие. Точные правила сопоставления не документированы, но обширные тесты выполненные 30 Августа 2011 указывают на следующий алгоритм:

- Взять первое слово непосредственно после *@*, где слово ограничено пробелом, символом недопустимым в именах пользователей (таких как `: , / ! ?`) или концом комментария.
- Удалить конечную точку `.` из полученной строки если возможно (и если в строке больше двух символов).
- Если оставшаяся строка оканчивается на `'` или `'s`, удалить этот кусок.
- Полученную строку попытаться сопоставить с именем пользователя, в котором удалены пробелы.

Пример: комментария оканчивается на `@O'Conner's.)`. Слово непосредственно за `@` - `O'Conner's.`, так как `'` и `.` допустимы в отображаемых именах. Затем удаляется конечная точка и в конце удаляется `'s`, в результате остается `O'Conner`.

Некоторые примеры поддерживающие уведомления:

- `@name some text`
- `@name: some text`
- `@name. Some text`
- `@name, some text`
- `some text, @name`
- `some text, @name, more text`
- `Some text, @name.`
- `This is mentioned in @name's comment.`
- `@P.` для обоих P. Smith и P. Jones (тому кто комментировал последним), но не P.Smith или P.Jones. Также как, `@P. Smith` обработается как `@P.`, что также соответствует P. Smith или P. Jones.
- `@psm` или `@psmith` для P Smith
- `@peters` или `@peterj` для Peter Smith или Peter Jones соответственно
- `@name...`

Примеры **не посылающие** уведомления:

- `abc@name`
- `*@name*`
- `*@name:*`
- `[@name](http://some-url)`
- `@[name](http://some-url)`
- `@P Smith`

<sub>перевод ответа на вопрос: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/282647)</sub>

Comment: Отлично, спасибо

Comment: Желательно еще источник указать

Comment: @VerNick, да, забыл его добавить